# How control what depenent version is installed when using PackageReference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, packagereference

I have a `C#` project that uses [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) to manage dependencies using NuGet. I am able to install top-level packages using the NuGet manager with no issues. However, I am looking for a way to force Nuget to install a specific version of one of the dependencies.

For example, I have a project called `MainProject.Data.`. In this project, I installed a package called `XYZ.Main`. But, `XYZ.Main` package has `XYZ.Secondary >= 2.1.0` listed as dependency. I want a way to be able to force Nuget to install `XYZ.Secondary 2.1.5`, not the latest which is `XYZ.Secondary  2.1.25`

How can I control which dependency to install?

Comment: Hi John, please check if my answer helps you handle this issue. If it helps, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> How control what depenent version is installed when using
> PackageReference

I am afraid you cannot install the specific dependency  `2.1.5` version when you install `XYZ.Main` package by **PackageReference** at the same time .

When you install the nuget package, it will automatically install the smallest version of the dependencies within the allowable range by default. **It is designed by that.**

**As a suggestion**,

To install the `XYZ.Secondary 2.1.5`, you should search dependency `XYZ.Secondary` on **Nuget Package Manager UI** and then update it to `2.1.5`. It will update the related version in your project to `2.1.5`.

Like this:

[image]

**Besides**, if you still want your requirements be implemented, you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click **Suggest a Feature**). The Team will consider your request carefully and hope they will give you a satisfactory reply.